# Show square matrix, then matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:
Show that if a square matrix $A$ satisfies the equation $A^2 + 2A + I = 0$, then $A$ must be invertible.

My work: Based on the section I read, I will treat I to be an identity matrix, which is a $1 \times 1$ matrix with a $1$ or as an square matrix with main diagonal is all ones and the rest is zero. I will also treat the $O$ as a zero matrix, which is a matrix with all zeros.

So the question wants me to show that the square matrix $A$ will make the following equation true. Okay so I pick $A$ to be $[-1]$, a $1 \times 1$ matrix with a $-1$ inside. This was out of pure luck.

This makes $A^2 = [1]$. This makes $2A = [-2]$. The identity matrix is $[1]$.

$1 + -2 + 1 = 0$. I satisfied the equation with my choice of $A$ which makes my choice of the matrix $A$ an invertible matrix.

I know matrix $A *$ the inverse of $A$ is the identity matrix.

$[-1] * inverse = [1]$. So the inverse has to be $[-1]$.

So the inverse of $A$ is $A$.

It looks right mathematically speaking.

Anyone can tell me how they would pick the square matrix A because I pick my matrix out of pure luck?

Comment: You don't get to "pick" the square matrix $A$. You have to show that *any* matrix that satisfies the equation $A^2+2A+I=0$ is invertible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse of $A$ is almost certainly not $A$.  You have $A^2+2A=-I$, or $A(A+2I)=-I$.  Multiplying by $-1$ you get $$A(-A-2I)=I$$

Hence the inverse of $A$ is $-A-2I$.

Comment: When you factor out a A, should it not be A(A + 2)? How did the identity matrix get in to the statement? If you multiplied -1 from both side, how come the first A does not become negative?

Comment: You can't add just 2, because 2 is a scalar and $A$ is a matrix.  The answer to your second question is: $-(xy)=(-x)y=x(-y)$.

Comment: You got a point there. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

(an alternative to your approach)

if $0=A^{2}+2A+I=\left(A+I\right)\left(A-I\right)$you have that the set $\left\{+1,-1\right\}$ contains all the eigenvalues of $A$. thus $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ and this is equivalent to being invertible.

Edit:

as LutzL has commented correctly, $A-I$ has to be replaced by $A+I$ and thus $\left\{-1,+1\right\}$ by $\left\{-1\right\}$. The arguments still work.

Comment: This question is before eigenvalues. So I can only use the concepts of square matrix, invertible matrix, identity matrix and zero matrix.

Comment: ah, what a pitty... but i think vadims approach does it quite nicely.

Comment: Wrong statement of binomial theorem. $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$, $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$. So the first formula mixes two quite different binomial formulas.

Comment: yes, indeed, thanks. but the argument still works. (edited)

Answer (score 0):

$$\det{A} \cdot \det{(A+2I)} =\det{[A(A+2I)]}=\det{(-I)}=\pm 1 \implies \det{A} \neq 0 \iff A \space \text{is invertible}$$

Comment: what is $\left|\cdot\right|$? - edit: ah, it's $\det$

Comment: @Max It's a shorthand for the determinant.

Comment: @Max It is the Determinant

Comment: How come you need to put the bars over the matrix? It does not seem to be absolute value sign.

Comment: $|A|$, where $A$ is a square matrix, is the symbol for the determinant of $A$, which is some scalar.

Comment: Oh I see. Interesting. I always seen as det(A) from the book. Nice to know there are other options to write it.

Comment: @Nicholas It's not very common usage. `\det` is easy LaTeX code, and $|\cdot |$ can be ambiguous, especially when used in combination with other interpretations of the symbol. But, sometimes it is intuitive.

Comment: @Arkamis It's irrelevant that's It's easy latex, It would just take a lot more space. Ambiguous when you know $A$ is a matrix? Not for humans. By the way I have never met a person who finished Linear Algebra I course, and doesn't know this notation.

Comment: Using that notation, distinguish the difference between matrix norm, the absolute value of the determinant, a vector norm, and the absolute value of a scalar. Its funny to say that LaTeX is irrelevant, yet make an argument for space, which is rarely relevant. Bars are useful, but should only be used in context, to distinguish between the many other uses of bars.

Comment: Not to mention, in other fields, matrices are named using different nomenclatural standards. In structural engineering, $[M]$ is common. $|[M]|$ is hideous.

Comment: @Arkamis Let's agree to disagree. I'll edit my post though to meet the standard notation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to show  **$A$ is invertible**. For this only you have to show $ det (A) \neq 0$.

Now since $A$ satisfies the polynomial equation $ x^{2} + 2x + 1 = 0$ (as $ A^{2} + 2 A + I = 0$ is given), which contains non-zero constant term $1$ so $ det (A) = 1 \neq 0$. Therefore $A$ has an inverse. [Q.E.D]

** Now if you have to find $A^{-1}$, then you can proceed as follows

$A^{2} +2 A + I = 0 $ .......(1)

Since *A has an inverse*, so multiplying both side of equation (1) by $A^{-1}$ we have

$A^{-1} (A^{2} + 2 A + I) = A^{-1}. 0 \implies A^{-1} . A^{2} +2 A^{-1}. A + A^{-1} .I=0 \implies A + 2I + A^{-1}=0 \implies A^{-1} = -A-2I $

Answer (score -2):

Since $A^2 + 2A + I = 0$, $(A + I)^2 = 0$.
Hence $A = -I$, for any size square matrix. 
Since the $det(-I) = 1$, the inverse exists.

Since $I* I = I$ and $-I * -I = I$

$A = -I * -I = A$

Thus, $A*A = I$, making $A$ its own inverse.

Another solution to this problem is as follows:

$A^2 + 2A = -I$

$A(A+2)= -I$
and thus $A(-A -2I) = I$ (Since the identity is basically 1), and thus $-A -2I$ is the inverse of $A$.

From earlier conclusion $A = -I$, and thus $-(-I) - 2I = -I = A$, so it remains that $A$ is its own inverse.

Comment: $(A+I)^2=0$ does not imply $A=-I$, unless the size of the matrices is $1\times 1$.